# how to hide fax field for guest user magento

Tags: magento-1.7

magento, At checkout page i want to hide fax field in billing address if user checkout as guest.I tried this code

`if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {}` 
but it not worked.

Please give me code for this.

And i want to hide fax field in backend(customer->address).but i could not find file. Please navigate me file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your template file of shipping .

```
<?php $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();?>
                        <?if($customer):?>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="shipping:fax"><?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="tel" name="shipping[fax]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getFax()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('fax') ?>" id="shipping:fax" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif;?>
```